# Durable functions for Chatterbot?

Tags: python, chatterbot

I'm looking to create and keep alive (without using it right away) an instance of a Chatterbot. Meaning I want to create the instance as the first thing, but then I won't be using it until a specific user input is captured, during down time the user will be in interacting with another bot.

Durable functions looks like the way to go, but I was wondering if there is an easier option, Chatterbot documentation doesn't seem to address this possibility.

Comment: Can you link to where you are reading regarding "durable functions"? This seems to be an Azure concept, which doesn't match your tags or anything I'm aware of in python. 

Also, what do you mean "first thing"? Are you familiar with object oriented programing? You may want to set up some instances using constructors that are built in to the Chatterbot library (You may have to override some constructor class to do this), or in the typical 

`if __name__ == __main__:`

statement at the bottom of each python class.

Comment: Another possibility:

How about something in pythons [__init__()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) function built int to each class? Setting up an instance of anything that you won't use for a while, is a typical place to put something like that.